# Python Regex re.sub not working as intended with dictionary lookup function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dictionary

I have one Py file working as a lookup like (constants.py):

```
constants = {'[%IP%]':'0.0.0.0'}
```

From my main file, I'm trying to replace a part of my string using the lookup.

```
from constants import constants
import re
path = r"[%IP%]\file.exe"
pattern = r'\[%.*?\%]'
def replace(match):
    return constants.get(match)
print(replace("[%IP%]")) # this bit works fine
print(re.sub(pattern, replace, path)) # this results in the matched pattern just vanishing
```

When I directly access the 'replace' function in my main file, it correctly outputs the matched result from the constants file dictionary.
But when I use the re.sub to substitute the pattern directly using the replace function with the lookup, it results in a string without the matched pattern at all.

So this is essentially the output for this (which isn't correct):

```
0.0.0.0
\file.exe
```

The desired output for this is:

```
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0\file.exe
```

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback you pass to `re.sub` will be called with a [Match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), not with a plain string. So the callback function needs to extract the string from that Match object.

Can be done like this:

```
def replace(match):
    return constants.get(match[0])
```

Comment: Thank you! It's been a long day at work, I didn't even pass the parameters with the function.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It is not you that needs to *pass* the parameters... that is done by the `re.sub` implementation. The code `re.sub(pattern, replace, path))` is fine.

Comment: That's absolutely correct. I just tried out a implementation using lambda and that worked too but I had to pass parameters in that, but I took your solution as the convenient one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I'll mark as Accepted is definitely one solution.
The other way around is to use a lambda function and pass the parameters like:

```
re.sub(pattern, lambda x: replace(x.group()), path))
```